# ftp_put successfully transfers file but with a file size of 0 bytes

Tags: php, ftp, server, webmin

I am trying to move a file from one subdomain to another on webmin. The file does move but at the destination it always has a size of 0 bytes.

```
    $source = '/home/webminuser1/public_html/some_file.php';
    $dest = '/home/webminuser2/public_html/some_file.php';
    $server = 'valid_server_name';

    $connection = ftp_connect($server);
    ftp_login($connection, 'webminuser2', 'some_password');
    ftp_pasv($connection, true);

    ftp_put($connection, $dest , $source , FTP_ASCII);
```

There was a similar question suggesting using passive mode and trying out both FTP_ASCII and FTP_BINARY. I tried both and am using passive mode as you can see(if I don't use it I get an error). So the problem is not there.

Any ideas what could be causing it? When I execute the script I get a very long loading time followed by an internal server error 500. The file is at it's destination but has a file size of 0 bytes. **It is important to note I am on an webmin server.**

Comment: Do you have error messages and notices enabled? If not, enable them and let us know if there are any output.

Comment: I do have them enabled but nothing appears. My only clues are the ones I stated: the 500 server error (that seems to be on timeout) and the 0 bytes file size.

Comment: I am thinking that the you might have an issue maybe with your ftp quota? Does the user whose details you are using have enough?

Comment: Not familiar with that. Where can I can check that?

Comment: Do you have an access to server-side log?

Comment: Why do you think that "ftp_put successfully transfers file" if you get "internal server error 500"?